# laravel sql получить массив

Tags: php, laravel

есть такой запрос:

```
$priceCheck = DB::select("SELECT products.id, products.in_stock, sku.price  FROM products INNER JOIN sku ON products.id = sku.product_id WHERE products.id IN ($preProducts)");
```

Он выдает массив вида:

```
array(Object, Object)
```

Мне же нужно

```
array(array(), array())
```

Как на этапе построения запроса это сделать?

Comment: Все пытаетесь 1600 записей показать?

Comment: @u_mulder уже другое. Дело в том что проблема была не с показом товаров, а с фильтрацией для нее, я прокатывался по всем 1600 товарам, строил объекты внутри, чтобы найти что там фильтруется, и это занимало тонну времени, сейчас поправил все, просто пытаюсь понять как массивы получить

Comment: В фасаде `DB` можно вызвать метод `setFetchMode`.

Comment: Глупая у вас затея. Смысл в ORM, чтобы получать объекты, с которыми удобно работать. А вы скатываетесь до самого дна. Что простой mysqli и PDO умеют.

Comment: Это не ORM, а ARM тогда))))

Comment: А почему не использовать toArray? (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-toarray) Да, он вернет массив объектов, и их нужно конвертировать в массив используя toArray, но можно и setFetchMode, как вам подсказал @u_mulder, чтобы сразу определить данные в массивы.